# Jquery before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, forms, submit

I have a list, (a simple list) from which i am able to select and set elements (using js), and then a form that allows me to choose how many elements i want, and a submit form.if one doesn't select an element, there is a script that throws an exception. The problem is that i want that the form doesn't submit, if an element is not selected, but not throw an exception, but to show me a message down the submit button (using jquery). my script below:

```
<? foreach ($types as $type):?>
<ul class = "product_types">
    <? if ($type->stock_2 > 0):?>
    <li id = 'product_types'><a href="#" onclick='selecteazaElement(<?= $type->id; ?>,<?= $type->stock_2; ?>);'><?= $type->label; ?></a></li>
    <? else: ?>
    <li id = 'product_unavailable_types'><label><?= $type->label; ?></label></li>
    <? endif; ?>

</ul>
<? endforeach; ?>
<form  name="addtobasket" method="POST" action="<?= Route::url('Add to Basket', array('sale_id' => $sale->id)); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="idOfSelectedItem" id="idOfSelectedItem" value="-1">
    <select name="number" id="number">
        <option value=0>Alege numarul de produse</option>    </select>
    <button type="submit" name = "submit" onclick="addtobasket";>Adauga in cos</button><br />
</form>
```

and the js that sets the list elements:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function selecteazaElement(id,stock)
    {
   document.addtobasket.idOfSelectedItem.value=id;
   window["canSubmit"] = true;
   var number23=document.addtobasket.number;
   number23.options.length=0;
   if (stock>=6)
   stock=6;
   for (i=1;i<=stock;i++)
    {
//alert ('id: '+id+'; stock: '+stock);
   number23.options[number23.options.length]=new Option(i, i);
   }
//window.status="my status";
}
```

Comment: JavaScript works on the html as seen by, and rendered in, the browser. Could you post the relevant html of that page (View Source)?

Comment: hmm.. the idea is: i just want to add a jquery event listener to that form. so that, if i try to submit it without having choosen an event from the list, to appear a mssage and not no submit the form... can it be possbile? thank you!

Comment: i'd like to see some rendered html output aswell

Answer (score 29):

Add a `submit` listener to the form. When it's submitted, check to see if an element is selected, and if not you can prevent the submission by using `return false`. Here's an example:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function()
{
    if (/* test case not true */) { 
        $('#myError').show();
        return false; 
    }

    // ... continue work
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can also handle the submit event with plain JavaScript like so:

```
var myform = document.getElementById('myForm');
myform.addEventListener('submit', function() { console.log('Submitted!'); return false; });
```

Comment: if i add the simplest event listener to the form (just to check if it works, i can;t manage to get it work...)code: <script>
$('#addtobasket').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});

</script>  and i have added an id to the form.

Comment: you have jQuery included?  This answer uses jQuery which you did not use in your question.

Comment: I tested my code on the HTML I gave, and it works fine. Did you use the exact code you showed me? Also, try running this to see if you're even selecting the right form: `console.log($('#addtobasket'));`.

Comment: @Bob, nice catch. Yeah, this question uses jQuery (which I recommend you use for event handling, since it keeps things consistent across browsers) -- give me a moment and I'll try to set it up for main JavaScript.