# jquery form event listener

Tags: jquery, events, forms, submit, listener

it is possible to make an event listener for a form, so that if one did not make an action (select any element from a list for example), the form WILL NOT submit, and eventually display an alert?

thank you!

Comment: did you mean to say that if the user does not change the default value of the dropdown, then it would trigger an `alert`?

Comment: why not give the alert after a submit button click if there was no change in the form?

Answer (score 3):

Possible indeed. Most straight forward way is handling the `change` event of all elements, raising some global flag there, then checking for that flag in the `submit` event:

```
$("#Form1 input,textarea,select").each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
        window["canSubmit"] = true;
    });
});

$("#Form1").submit(function() {
    if (window["canSubmit"] === true)
        return true;
    alert("Please fill the form");
    return false;
});
```

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/Wahr2/

Comment: hmm..very cool, but i have a big problem. the selectable elements are not included in the form in my case. the reformulated question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851819/jquery-before-submitting-the-form thank you!

Comment: @dana so just change `$("#Form1 input,textarea,select").each(function() {` to: `$("input,textarea,select").each(function() {` meaning you'll catch the change of any element, regardless where it's located.

Comment: cool... so it is not necessary to have in included in my form. super! i'll try right now and tell you what happened:) thanks!

Comment: hmm... the problem is that my select elements are a little genuine. meaning, that i don;t actually have an input html element (select, radio, checkbox, etc), but a simple unordered list. and a little javascript that sets some vaues on li element push. and so, the script doesn;t work for li elements :( the code is in the first comment link.

Comment: @dana still doable. In the code triggered by clicking the list items, just add `window["canSubmit"] = true`.

Comment: i tried, but it still submits me the form. i kept the script you showed me in jsfiddle, added it before my js script, then i added in my js script the window["canSubmit"] = true . still no result

Comment: @dana can you post link to the jsFiddle you updated? I'll try to see what went wrong.

Comment: the updated code is here in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851819/jquery-before-submitting-the-form thank you!

Comment: @dana so it should work fine once you add `id="Form1"` to your form and have my above code. (`$("#Form1").submit(function() { ...` you need to have this inside `$(document).ready()` block by the way sorry if it's not clear.

Comment: so i did like this: $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#Form1").submit(function() {
    if (window["canSubmit"] === true)
        return true;
    alert("Please fill the form");
    return false;
});
   // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
 
</script>  but no result. also added form1 id to the form;

Answer (score 1):

You can wire-up this action (select any element from a list) on a click of submit button and check if any of list element is selected or not else fire a alert

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#Submit').click(function(){   
    if (!$("#mySelect option:selected").length)
        alert("Select a value"); 
    });
 });
```

Comment: i think the OP did not mention about clicking but only on validating if the selected value inside the select option is the default or not

Comment: But i guess this has to be checked on form submit rite..?

Answer (score 1):

This should work. http://jsfiddle.net/eLgEZ/

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="$('#form').data('valuesChanged',true)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="if($('#form').data('valuesChanged') == undefined){alert('iiik')}else{alert('ok lets submit')};return false"/>
</form>
```

You will however need to add a listener to all form elements that when changed will set the form data 'valuesChanged'

**EDIT**

just remeber to remove the "return false" at the end of the onclick statement of the submit button.

Comment: what if the selectable elements are outside the form like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851819/jquery-before-submitting-the-form thanky you!

Comment: My solution would still work, just try moving the input checkbox outside the form.

Comment: the problem is that i don;t have a classinc input. i have some list elements, and a js that allows me to select them, and add some actions for them. i would like that i would have this event set on those li elements practically. is this possible?

Comment: In that case i need to know exactly what the js does and how you interface with the li elements. However, that is beyond the scope of this question...

Comment: the full code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851819/jquery-before-submitting-the-form