# How to prevent button from submitting the form and call Javascript method (with twist)?

Tags: javascript, forms

I don't know why it's very hard to find the answer for this simple problem. This Q/A is to help my fellow Javascript newbies like me to help understand the catch in selectively stopping the form cancellation.

I just write a very simple javascript function:

```
myfunc()
{
    if (conditionsatisfied) 
    {
        $("#myform").submit();
        return true;
    else 
    {
        alert ('there's a mistake on the form!');
        return false;
    }
}
```

which I hoped will allow the form to submit if the validation is true. if not, stop the form submit.

but, even though the validation is run correctly (the alert box is shown), the form will be still submitted. it happens whether I call the function from:

```
<form id="myform" action="target.php" onsubmit="myfunc();">
```

or

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myfunc();">
```

don't asked me to change the input type into button, because I've tried that, and for some strange reason, it causes the form to sometimes invalid on the receiver page (target.php).

the only way I can make the submit work is by put the return false on the inline javascript:

```
<form id="myform" action="target.php" onsubmit="myfunc(); return false;">
```

or

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myfunc(); return false;">
```

but that would defeat my purpose to "continue the form submission when everything is okay, and halt when it's not okay" because I can't control the `return false;` code. so that's the entire egg and chicken chase I've been confused for some time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery before submitting the form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851819/jquery-before-submitting-the-form)

Comment: There are many similar questions and answers. That's just one of them. I'm not sure why you couldn't find them, I searched for `[jquery] prevent form submission`.

Comment: I also search for question like that, but many answers I read seems to always omitting the "**return** myfunc();" part, and usually add "return false;" after the myfunc(). thus leave me in the dark of a seemingly correct code, but it's not working.

Comment: Most of them don't use inline Javascript, they use Javascript event binding instead.

Comment: yea. I've read a glimpse about that. but I guess javascript event binding is still beyond my league for now. I spent 3 hours just to find out the problem with return false. So I guess I will stick to the traditional method a little longer before moving out to the more modern ones. I would like to try it sometimes though. :)

Answer (score 1):

Then something occurred to me, that this is inline javascript code. Sure I can put some code on the inline code, right? When I look again at the inline code `myfunc(); return false;`, the important "return" that can affect the form submission cancellation is when it happens on the **inline code**, not on the function. I remember my function returns boolean. so I check for the boolean, and the code is revised to this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="if (myfunc()==false) return false;">
```

and it works! and then I look at the code again, and realized that because myfunc() already return false when the inline javascript should return false, I can further simplify the code:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return myfunc();">
```

so after all these times, I only missing the "return" code. I hope this can helps. :)

Comment: And then you'll realise that a form can be submitted without pressing the submit button and *myfunc* won't be called. So you'll move the listener to the form: `<form ... onsubmit="return myfunc()" ..>` and you'll have code just like millions of other forms on the web… :-)

Comment: true. actually, my actual implementation is on the onsubmit. :) I just don't understand why many answers on the web is omitting the "return", thus in turn makes me wondering what's wrong with my seemingly correct code. XD thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The *return* is only used if the intent is to interrupt submission. Sometimes the submit listener will just update some fields or do some processing and allow submit to proceed unconditionally.

Comment: yes I understand that. But I think it's a good programming habit to always include the return, because we also can handle whether we want to interrupt the form submission or not from the function itself. but it's just me. :) thanks.